# My Roland Piano HP 1700L sustains on it own and goes off when it gets to its climax. what could be the problem

Tags: piano

Am having a problem with my Roland HP1700L piano... it sustains on its own and goes off when the sustain gets to its climax.. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you saying that the pedal is reversed? It stops sustaining with the pedal all the way down?

Answer (score 1):

Going on MattPuttnam's suggestion, A lot of pedal attachments have a reverse/polarity switch.   It's screwed me up quite a few times.   I've even seen settings on some electonic piano's that will reverse the polarity of the pedal.  I would start with a check of the pedal itself.  Most likely that's all it is.

If it's not that, next, you are going to have to look into the owners manual of the Roland and see what kind of options/affects that might have caused it.
Unless you have some specific settings established, it might be easier just to reset it to default.   Again, there should be something in the owners manual about that.

Comment: Could well be. I played a whole gig with a borrowed pedal that only worked in reverse after someone stole mine. That was a fun gig, holding on to pedal for no sustain!